# How to split a list that has multiple "="?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list where some of elements have only one "=", others have many:

```
l1 = [
    'Gene.ensGene=ENSG00000111058',
    'Gene.refGene=IL2,IL21',
    'Gene.refGene=LIN7A,ACSS3',
    'GeneDetail.ensGene=dist=38306,dist=117597',
    'GeneDetail.refGene=dist=112857,dist=27258'
]
```

How can I split this list by the first "="? For example:

- `'Gene.ensGene=ENSG00000111058'` → `'Gene.ensGene','ENSG00000111058'`
- `'GeneDetail.refGene=dist=112857,dist=27258'` → `'GeneDetail.refGene','dist=112857,dist=27258'`

Comment: Do you want a new list where each element is a tuple like you explained ?

Comment: Is there a documented specification for the data you're parsing?

Comment: You can split each element with `=` and then join the elements except the first element if you want to retain all text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` has a `maxsplit` argument, so if you only want to split by the first `=` encountered you can just set `maxsplit` to one

```
'GeneDetail.ensGene=dist=38306,dist=117597'.split('=', maxsplit=1)
# ['GeneDetail.ensGene', 'dist=38306,dist=117597']

for line in l1:
    split_line = line.split('=', maxsplit=1)
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `split()` method with the `maxsplit` parameter set to `1`:

```python
l1 = ['Gene.ensGene=ENSG00000111058', 'Gene.refGene=IL2,IL21', 'Gene.refGene=LIN7A,ACSS3', 'GeneDetail.ensGene=dist=38306,dist=117597', 'GeneDetail.refGene=dist=112857,dist=27258']
l2 = [e.split("=", 1) for e in l1]
print(l2)
```